# Why doesn't GIMP support CMYK?

Tags: gimp, cmyk

Why does GIMP not support CMYK?  This is a feature  that I really need as a user and I don't know why it is not supported in GIMP by default.  Is there possibly a way of which I could add support for it via an extension or plugin?  Should this turn up nothing, would there be another software program with CMYK support which would run on Ubuntu?

Comment: Only ask one question per post please.

Comment: They are working on it as part of switching out their whole backend, cf. https://www.gimp.org/news/2017/01/15/2016-in-review/ / https://www.gimp.org/news/2017/01/16/pippin-patreon-fundraising-started/

Answer (score 13):

### CYMK Support

GIMP is an open source program and so is built and maintained by the community.  The [GIMP FAQ](http://www.gimp.org/docs/userfaq.html#cmyk) states:

> It is clear from the [product vision](http://gui.gimp.org/index.php/GIMP_UI_Redesign#product_vision) that GIMP eventually needs to support CMYK, but it is impossible to say when someone finds the free time and motivation to add it. In the meantime **it is possible to work with CMYK to some extent using plug-ins, such as the [Separate+](http://cue.yellowmagic.info/softwares/separate-plus/index.html) plug-in.**

### Alternative Software

Alternative software to GIMP can be found by using the popular [Alternative.To](http://alternativeto.net/software/gimp/?platform=linux) website.

Answer (score 5):

There's always [Krita](https://krita.org/). It seems to be geared more towards painting, but supports CMYK natively.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble installing `separate+` cause my Ubuntu did not have `gimpui-2.0 plugin`.

To install:

Open synaptic and search `separate+`

I eventually found a package for GIMP that had utility for CMYK colors: `gimp-plugin-registry`

Comment: This seems to be a commentary on [this answer](/a/243393) instead of a stand-alone answer.